# LTSpice Problem with AD8422/AD8221/?

Tags: ltspice, simulation

My LTSpice simulation (fresh download from yesterday) always stops (gets super slow) after approx. 12.4 ms, when using the AD8422 or AD8221 (probably also with other amps of this type) in the following configuration, which is to my understanding an allowed operation state:
[image]

I checked the validity of this operation with Analog's Diamond Plot Tool, which seems fine as well:
[image]

LTSPice gets stuck at this point:

[image]

Up to this point (12.4 ms), the circuit works as expected (voltage follower/unity-gain buffer). I also tried activating the option "noopiter", which makes the simulation run some us more, but very slow (0.1 us simulation time per 2 s real time).

I was able to run the simulation, when either:

- increasing the REF voltage above GND (e.g., +1 V)
- connecting the V_In- pin to Vout instead of GND (from my understanding this should not be necessary with the AD8422)

Am I missing something? What happens here?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the model. I added 10 nF to the output and then the simulation got stuck shortly, simulating another 15 ms and then get stuck again, and repeating that process until 80 ms are over. But it is rather sensitive, changing it to 100 nF it will stall at 35 ms and go no further. Adding a load didn't help either.

Comment: Tested with microcap v12. All is ok. https://archive.org/details/micro-cap-12-full-cd-version-12.2.0.5

Comment: Note that it seems that a file with AD8221 exist in LT datasheets and it works ...

Comment: Try adding `.options cshunt=1f` onto the schematic as a SPICE directive (shortcut key 'S') and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, there is an issue with the model/subcircuit.  The easiest way to solve it is to add the following SPICE directive (shortcut key <kbd>S</kbd>) onto your schematic:

```
.options cshunt=1f
```

[image]

This adds a shunt capacitor of 1 femto-farad from every node (including the nodes within the opamp) to ground.  If you want to do a more surgical strike, you have to manually edit the `AD8422.lib` file (or other library files with the same opamp structure) and modify the diode model `DZ` found at the end of the subcircuit.

Change it from this:

```
.MODEL DZ D(IS=1e-15 BV=50 RS=1)
```

to this:

```
.MODEL DZ D(IS=1e-15 BV=50 RS=1 CJO=1f)
```

[image]

The subcircuit is poorly constructed because all the diode models defined within should have a non-zero `CJO` to prevent these convergence problems.  There are 6 diode `.model` statements in the file and none of them have a `CJO` defined.  I guess and checked one-by-one to see which was causing your specific problem, but the other ones have the potential to cause different problems in different scenarios.  So instead of manually "fixing" ADI's models, it's probably better to just use the `cshunt` option and call it a day.

Comment: Thank you a lot! As you said and thoroughly analyzed, it works now. Very interesting insights into the numerical challenges also. Great answer!